# Display custom comments field for first level only

Tags: functions

I have simple fuction that adds additional comment form field called "Subject":

```
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_before', 'additional_fields' );
add_action( 'comment_form_before_fields', 'additional_fields' ); 

function additional_fields () {
    echo '<p class="comment-form-subject">'.
    '<label for="subject">' . __( 'Your subject' ) . '</label>'.
    '<input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';
}
```

It works fine, but just now it adds "Subject" field to every comment form.

I need to add this field only for first level/depth of comments.

My goal is:
When user will reply directly to post, he will get "Subject" field in reply form.
When user will reply to comment, he will not see "Subject" field in reply form.

Comment: Select the correct answer when you see it, so I can award bounty.

Answer (score 6):

### The Reply links

I assume your *Reply* links look like this:

```
<a class="comment-reply-link" href="/2013/12/29/hello-world/?replytocom=32#respond" 
 onclick="return addComment.moveForm('comment-32', '32', 'respond', '1')">Reply</a>
```

and the *Cancel Reply* link:

```
<a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" 
href="/2013/12/29/hello-world/#respond" style="">Cancel reply</a>
```

The Javascript method `addComment.moveForm` is defined in `/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js`.

### Demo plugin:

To hide the extra *Subject* field for comments replies, you can try to check for the `replytocom` GET parameter for the non-Javascript case and hook into the *click* event for the Javascript case.

Here is a demo **Comment Subject** plugin: `/wp-content/plugins/comment-subject/comment-subject.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Comment Subject
 */

/**
 * Add extra Subject comment field when there is no replytocom in the url 
 */
function additional_fields () {

    $url_query = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY );

    if( FALSE === stripos( $url_query, 'replytocom' ) )
    { 
        echo '<p class="comment-form-subject">'.
        '<label for="subject">' . __( 'Your subject' ) . '</label>'.
        '<input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';
    }
}

add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_before', 'additional_fields' );
add_action( 'comment_form_before_fields', 'additional_fields' ); 

/**
 * Add jQuery and load the custom "script.js"
 */    
function custom_scripts() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_enqueue_script(  'my-comment-subject', 
                            plugins_url( 'js/script.js' , __FILE__ ), 
                            array( 'jquery' ), 
                            '1.0.0', 
                            TRUE 
                     );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```

where you add the file `/wp-content/plugins/comment-subject/js/script.js` containing:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', 'a.comment-reply-link', function( event ) {
    jQuery('p.comment-form-subject').hide();
});

jQuery(document).on( 'click', 'a#cancel-comment-reply-link', function( event ) {
    jQuery('p.comment-form-subject').show();
});
```

Comment: Due to the original poster, User3136701, not replying in any way or sort. Your accuracy of code, and highest upvote, I have selected your answer as the bounty winner.

Comment: @MrJustin thanks. I hope you can use it and good luck with your project.

Comment: Actually it wasn't for me.  The user 'USER3136701' is the one who asked the question.  I just placed a bounty on it to be nice, hopefully he can use it :)  I use a custom Walker for my comments, so I don't actually use a list at all, I use HTML5 articles and sections.

Comment: ok, thanks for sharing. I hope @USER3136701 appreciates your kindly awarded bounty, but I guess we will never know ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Let me throw a simple CSS-only solution into the hat:

```
/* Hide the subject for nested comments (level 2 and below) */
.comment .comment p.comment-form-subject {
    display: none;
}
```

This solution assumes you are using [`comment_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_class).

Answer (score 1):

How about using a conditional to check if there are comments? If not, display a different comment form.

```
$num_comments = get_comments_number( $post_id );
if($num_comments > 0) {
    // Your function to edit comment fields if there ARE comments. Or nothing if the default fields are fine.
}
else
{
//We have comments, so run your function, as above.
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_before', 'additional_fields' );
add_action( 'comment_form_before_fields', 'additional_fields' ); 

function additional_fields () {
    echo '<p class="comment-form-subject">'.
    '<label for="subject">' . __( 'Your subject' ) . '</label>'.
    '<input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';
}
} //End else
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet inside your single.php, paste it in while loop before comments open function, this will get you solution.

```
$args = array( 'post_id' => $post->ID,'count' => true );
 $comments = get_comments($args);

 if( $comments == 0  ) :
    add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_before', 'additional_fields' );
    add_action( 'comment_form_before_fields', 'additional_fields' );
 endif;

 function additional_fields () {
    echo '<p class="comment-form-subject">'.
    '<label for="subject">' . __( 'Your subject' ) . '</label>'.
    '<input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';
 }
```